# How to end/kill all incoming SSH connections?

Tags: ssh, python, kill

I am developing a some code in order to communicate between a PC and a Raspberry Pi via SSH. When the PC opens a SSH connection to the RPi a window with a short message pops up on the RPi's screen. When there are no open SSH connections said window closes itself. Everything works just fine so far.

Now, I want to add a button in said window on the RPi in order to terminate all SSH incoming connections. Is there a Unix command for that?
A Python module or method that does that would be fine as well, since the RPi's code is written in Python.

According to my research terminating a SSH connection can be done by killing the corresponding process via its PID. Since I want to kill all SSH processes/connections autonomously I am looking for an easier solution.

Thanks for your help!

(The Raspberry Pi runs on Raspbian 8 (jessie))

Answer (score 1):

Killing all the SSH server processes isn't hard if you have `pkill`/`pgrep`, just run `pkill sshd`. The problem is separating the main SSH daemon from the per-connection ones, and leaving that one alive.

A simple workaround for that would be to shut down the server, kill the remaining per-connection processes, and then restart the server, e.g. on a systemd system:

```
systemctl stop sshd
pkill sshd
systemctl start sshd
```

Or, given that `sshd` is probably set up to write a PID file, we can read the PID of the main process from there, and skip that. On my Debian with systemd, it's written in `/run/sshd.pid` but it could be set to something else in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` with the `PidFile` option.

`pgrep` gives the output one PID per line, so we can use `grep` to remove the line with the main PID (`grep -x` should be used to avoid partial matches):

```
#!/bin/bash
mainpid=$(cat /run/sshd.pid)
pids=$(pgrep sshd | grep -vxe "$mainpid")
kill $pids
```

The unquoted expansion of `$pids` splits the string on whitespace so `kill` gets the PIDs separately.

You'd have to run that as `root`, since there's actually two per-connection processes: one running as `root`, one as the logged-in user. Or, if you want to just kill the `sshd`  processes owned by your user, use `pgrep -u username sshd`.

Comment: rather than `pids=....kill $pids` I'd suggest `killall -HUP sshd ; sleep 1 ; killall -TERM sshd ; systmctl restart sshd`

Comment: @symcbean, HUP is actually a good idea in that it looks like it'd terminate the per-connection processes, but causes the main process to just reload the configuration. Not sure if there's any reason the TERM would be needed after the HUP though. As far as I can see, the unprivileged per-connection `sshd` terminates of either, and the privileged one catches either signal or the unprivileged counterpart dying. As for `killall`, well, [it does something really different on some systems](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E86824_01/html/E54764/killall-1m.html), so I'd rather avoid using it.